# Cacncelling Loop when minimum is reached

Tags: c++, numerical-methods

I'm new to C++ and coing in general but I want to write a numerical program to calculate the collision of two nuclei interacting with the coloumb force.

I want to know what the minimum value of d is. I thought I could do a while loop with d>d as an argument, such that it repeats as long as the new value of d is smaller than the old value it repeats.

But apparently it doesn't work that way. What could I do to fix this?
I thought about using arrays that delete themselves if the argument " d>d " isn't fulfilled.

Do you guys have any tips? Thanks!

```
#include "iostream"

#include "math.h"

void At_col();
using namespace std;

long double m_He = 6.64e-27;
long double m_Li = 1.16e-26;

long double K = 2.31e-23;

long double a_He;
long double a_Li;

long double v_He = 4.39e6;
long double v_Li = 0;

long double x_He = 49;
long double x_Li = 50;
long double d = x_Li - x_He;

double dk = 13;
double dt;
long double t;

int main() {

  while (d >= d) {
    if (d > 0.1) {
      dt = pow(10, -dk);
      At_col();
    } else {
      if (d > 1e-2) {
        dt = pow(10, -(dk + 1));
        At_col();
      } else {
        if (d > 1e-3) {
          dt = pow(10, -(dk + 2));
          At_col();
        } else {
          if (d > 1e-4) {
            dt = pow(10, -(dk + 3));
            At_col();
          } else {
            if (d > 1e-5) {
              dt = pow(10, -(dk + 4));
              At_col();
            } else {
              if (d > 1e-6) {
                dt = pow(10, -(dk + 5));
                At_col();
              } else {
                if (d > 1e-7) {
                  dt = pow(10, -(dk + 6));
                  At_col();
                } else {
                  if (d > 1e-8) {
                    dt = pow(10, -(dk + 7));
                    At_col();
                  } else {
                    if (d > 1e-9) {
                      dt = pow(10, -(dk + 8));
                      At_col();
                    } else {
                      if (d > 1e-10) {
                        dt = pow(10, -(dk + 9));
                        At_col();
                      } else {
                        if (d > 1e-11) {
                          dt = pow(10, -(dk + 10));
                          At_col();
                        } else {
                          if (d > 1e-12) {
                            dt = pow(10, -(dk + 11));
                            At_col();
                          } else {
                            if (d > 1e-13) {
                              dt = pow(10, -(dk + 12));
                              At_col();
                            }

                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
  return 0;
}

void At_col() {
  a_He = -1 * K / m_He / pow(x_He - x_Li, 2);

  a_Li = K / m_Li / pow(x_He - x_Li, 2);

  v_Li = v_Li + (a_Li * dt);

  x_Li = x_Li + (v_Li * dt);

  v_He = v_He + (a_He * dt);

  x_He = x_He + (v_He * dt);

  t = t + dt;

  d = x_Li - x_He;

  cout << "t = " << t << "|d = " << d << "|x_He = " << x_He << "|x_Li = " << x_Li <<
    "|v_Li = " << v_Li << "|a_Li = " << a_Li << "|v_He= " << v_He <<
    endl;
}
```

Comment: `d` is a `long double` ie a single floating point number therefore `while ( d >= d )` is always `true`

Comment: your description in text "repeats as long as the new value of d is smaller than the old value it repeats" implies that there are two values involved. One would expect something like `d_old >= d_new`.

Comment: Your strange indentation (like the line `}}}}}}}}}}}}};return 0;}`) doesn't make your code more readable

Comment: it seems like this long chain of if else is doing the same in all cases. Something like `dt = pow( 10 , -(dk + log10(d)));`

Comment: @RichardCritten Strictly speaking, `d >= d` is not always `true` (for floating points): [Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6383d201610e7762). ;-)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat if OP understands NaNs the question would be different.

Answer (score 2):

You want to compare two values, so you need to have two values.

Your code can look something like this:

```
  long double dt = 0.0;
  long double previous_dt = 100.0;

  while (dt < previous_dt) { 
         // do your calculations
         long double next_dt = ....
         
         // swap the values
         previous_dt = dt;
         dt = next_dt;
  }
```

Your code is very unreadable due to strange intendation. Most of your `if-else` cases seem to do the same thing. The only thing that is different is the `x` in `dt = pow( 10 , -(dk + x));` and that `x` can be calculated in a simpler fashion than those many cases. Moreover you should try to avoid global variables. If they are too many to be passed to a function you can define a data structure that contains them and then pass an instance of that data structure to the function.